# Clearing previously printed strings

Tags: c, output, stdout

I have to write a program that compiles a Brainfuck to C. BF comes from stdin, length of it is unknown. I mustn't use any memory functions (like malloc), so that I can't store the output in a variable (unless I use `char out[99999]`). However, if there's an error (like `++]`) I don't want to see anything in stdout. How can I do clear the previously printed strings?

```
if (c == '+')
    printf("x = x+1");
...
if (c == ']' and there wasn't any '[')
    remove the "x = x+1" and eveything else
    display an error message.
```

Comment: The simplest thing is to just buffer the output, and only print it at the end. And then if there is an error you can just toss the buffer. If you want to ask the terminal to clear itself, you can do it but you will have to do things that won't work on every single terminal.

Comment: `stdout` most likely will be a file, not the terminal.

Comment: @ChrisBeck Can you show me an example for that please?

Comment: Write to a temp file and only cat that if you are sure. no malloc, "infinite" space.

Comment: @klenium: Yeah, if you aren't allowed to malloc you should use a tempfile like PeterSchneider suggests. Otherwise you can only get working memory in O(1) sized chunks, and imo its most natural to have a large buffer to work with for this

Comment: Well, I've read again what is my job, and I mustn't use `malloc free calloc realloc fopen fclose sizeof`. :D Not so important, I guess my teacher will accept it if I say if the program returns 1, don't read the output. But isn't there an easy way for it? I know in PHP there're `ob_*` functions which know what I need. Something like those?

Comment: No fopen? Just use open/write! (Your teacher should be clear in what s/he's asking. "No file system access" would be a good wording for no file system access.) If you are on  Linux you may consider `memfd_create()`. If you *really* can't do such thing just allocate 1 GB or so statically in an array.